# Set TextBlock's text to string plus binding item?

Tags: c#, listview, binding

I have a `ListView` with multiple `TextBlock`s in it. Is it possible to have something such as this?

```xml
TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" Text="Author: {Binding data.author}"
```

or would it be better to just add it to data.author when that is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's XAML you could use StringFormat

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=data.author, StringFormat=Author: {0}}"/>
```